# unsigned int causes infinite for-loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, unsigned-integer

There are two loops below. The first one works well while the second one is an infinite loop. Why?

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "i= " << i << std::endl; // this gives proper result
}

for (unsigned int i=3; i>=0; --i)
{
    std::cout << "i= " << i << std::endl; // infinite loop
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An `unsigned int` can never be less than 0.  That's what makes it *unsigned*.  If you turn on some warning flags, your compiler should tell you about your problem:  `i >= 0` is *always true* for an `unsigned` value.

Clang, for example, required no special flags at all to warn:

```
example.cpp:5:29: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true
      [-Wtautological-compare]
    for (unsigned int i=3; i>=0; --i)
                           ~^ ~
1 warning generated.
```

GCC required `-Wextra`:

```
example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
example.cpp:5: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true
```

Answer (score 3):

`unsigned int` cannot be less than zero (which is what loop's condition is checking). When `i` in your second loop is decremented from 0, it wraps around to `UINT_MAX` and the loop goes on.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers (so far) are all correct; since `i` is unsigned, `i >= 0` is always true, and so you have an infinite loop.

But that doesn't tell you how to fix it.  If you want to iterate over an unsigned range from, say, 3 down to 0, there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to do it. Other than changing the type of `i` or the direction of the range (and there may be reasons you can't do that), you could do this:

```
for (unsigned int i=3; ; --i)
{
    std::cout << "i= " << i << std::endl;
    if (i == 0) break;
}
```

It's not as clean as a simple `for` loop with no `break` but it does the job.

Comment: I usually hate to pop in like this, but you might want to check my answer about how to get rid of that pesky `break`. ;)

Comment: @syam: Please, break in! I find my version more readable, but others may differ.

Comment: Well I agree on pure readability, but mine is a well known pattern so readability is not much an issue once you know it, and it's just a bit easier to write. Just figured I'd notify you in case you didn't know it yet, thought it might interest you. :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Keith Thompson's answer, there is another way to write it that doesn't require a `break` inside the loop:

```
for (unsigned int i = 3; i--; ) {
    std::cout << "i= " << i << std::endl;
}
```

Notice how `i--` acts both as the termination condition and as the afterthough, all in one. The use of the postfix decrement operator is important because it guarantees you're actually executing the loop 3 times, starting at 2 on the first iteration and ending at 0, included.

Comment: Why does this work? It's neat that it does, but will it always work?

Answer (score 2):

The minimum value for `unsigned int i` is 0; anything else would be negative and require a sign bit which is specifically what an `unsigned` int won't have.

So `i >= 0` will always evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

In your second loop ,the condition to stop the loop is that  `i` must be less than 0. The range of `unsigned int` is `0 to 65535`. so, here `unsigned int i` can't be less than zero. So, your condition is always true as a result the loop become infinite. Using a `signed int` can solve the problem.